# Banner position off upon window resize with sticky nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've encountered an issue with a sticky nav/banner image duo I'm trying to implement. 
Check it out here: http://lucid-build.com/stack/sticky/
The issue is, when I resize the window, the position of the banner is off. Otherwise, it acts as it's supposed to.
Any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

[edit] here's the script!

```
function resizeBanner() {
    var bannerH = $(".banner img").height();
    $(".banner").css("height", bannerH);
}

function fixedNav() {
    var logoT = $(".logo").offset().top;
    var bannerH = $(".banner img").height();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > logoT ) {
            $("#header").addClass("fixed").css(("height"),120);
            $(".banner").css(("margin-top"),-bannerH+120);
            $("body").css(("margin-top"),bannerH+18);       
        } else {
            $("#header").removeClass("fixed").css(("height"),("auto"));
            $(".banner").css(("margin-top"),0);
            $("body").css(("margin-top"),0);
        }
    });
}


$(window).resize(function() {
    resizeBanner();
});

$(window).load(function() {
    resizeBanner();
    fixedNav();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    resizeBanner();
});
```

Comment: Any code for us to check out? How is this sticky nav/banner actually made sticky?

Comment: Just added the script to my original post! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add to your element's css that has the class "banner" :

```
position : absolute;
bottom : 0;
```

PS : actually your box is resizing right but it set in the top left by default of the header that you set. As the parent box is set on position : relative, all the absolute element in will refer to that parent and not to the full document.

Comment: Oh my gosh, what an easy fix! I feel kind of silly now haha. Thank you so much!